# SQLAlchemy engine absolute path URL in windows

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to a sqlite-database file in a python 3.3 application on a windows 7 x64 machine. To do so, the documentation states:

```
# sqlite://<nohostname>/<path>
# where <path> is relative:
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')

# or absolute, starting with a slash:
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db')
```

I would like to use the absolute path, what is the windows-equivalent to `sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db`? The database is stored in `C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Appname/mydatabase.db`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On Windows it's a bit tricky, because you have to escape the backslashes:

```
sqlite:///C:\\path\\to\\database.db
```

Also, as Windows doesn't have the concept of `root` and instead uses drives, you have to specify absolute path with 3 slashes:

```
sqlite:///C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Appname\\mydatabase.db
```

Comment: Note that _the string passed to SQLite_ doesn't need double backslashes. You only need to escape the backslashes if you're typing them in a non-raw Python string. (i.e. you quote the backslashes for Python's parser, not for SQLite's parser.) Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlite

Answer (score 3):

According to [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlite), URL can be defined as follows as well.

- Relative Path

(this worked in windows as well)

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
```

- Absolute Path

```py
# Windows alternative using raw string
engine = create_engine(r'sqlite:///C:\path\to\foo.db')
```