# Flask SQLAlchemy Can't Connect to Database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app that I'm trying to connect to an SQLite DB. I have the db file in the same directory as the app but when I give command to create_all I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to
> open database file (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

This is a snippet of the code I am using.

```
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dont look at me im a secret'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/thisproject/database.db'
    app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
    app.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = False
    
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    
    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')
        active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
    
    
    user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy engine absolute path URL in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260067/sqlalchemy-engine-absolute-path-url-in-windows)

Comment: For some reason I had my app named main and it was causing issues along with this. SO yes this works

Comment: So, the fix was actually to change your app name to make the database connection work ? Or did you also had to change the path ?

Comment: both, I changed the path first and got the same error. Once I renamed my app to 'app' I was able make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11117210/truth) is onto something here.
It seems you are not specifying the path to the sqlite database correctly.

Your path should look like:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\me\\PycharmProjects\\thisproject\\database.db'
```

Comment: I updated the path and I get the same error. I actually had this on one of my many revisions trying to make it work lol

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my app file name to 'app.py' then update the path to the db as follows:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\me\\PycharmProjects\\thisproject\\database.db'
```

In order to get this to work